# Easy Image Gallery - Retrieve Serialized Data

Tags: gallery, post-meta

I am using Easy Image Gallery. It is called: `_easy_image_gallery` and looks like it's an array like 1234,5432,2345,.....

Now, Easy Image Gallery update to 1.3 is saving into a meta called: `_easy_image_gallery_v2` and the content is something like this:

```
[0] => a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"DATA";a:5:{i:0;s:5:"62255";i:1;s:5:"62259";i:2;s:5:"62261";i:3;s:5:"62263";i:4;s:5:"62265";}s:9:"SHORTCODE";s:3:"569";}}
```

My question is: How can I "decode" this gibberish from v2 into a nice array just like before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is [Serialized Data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11818086/800452). WordPress does this automagically when trying to save an array or object to the database. The [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function will unserialize the data if you pass the right parameters:

```
$array = get_post_meta(
    $post->ID,              // The post ID you want metadata from
    '_key_name',            // The meta key name
    true                    // Whether to attempt to unserialize or return the raw value.
);
```

PHP has a built in function to deal with this too such as [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php). WordPress also has it's own function called [`maybe_unserialize()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) which will attempt to unserialize the given string.

Comment: each day i learn something !... work perfectly thanks !